# Need some advice with MySQL code, I need to make the code list off all the purchases in a bill with the highest total cost

Tags: mysql

Basically, I'm using a database of a restaurant, I need the code to list off all the food bought **(name, category, price, amount etc)**, but only from the bill that has the highest total price. I tried using `sum(max())` to get the total price, but it would show error 1111 which is invalid use of group function, I tried to look up fixes but none of the results were helpful

I feel like it's also important to note that **all_data** is actually a view.

```
Select name, category, amount, if(amount>1, price*amount,price)
From all_data
Where (select sum(if(amount>1,amount*price,price)) from all_data)=(select max(sum(if(amount>1,amount*price,price))) from all_data)
```

Comment: Can you share your table definition and some data

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` to a subquery where we can get all the food bought that has the highest total price :

```
select t.*, s.total
from all_data t
inner join (
  Select name, category, amount, price, sum(price*amount) as total
  From all_data
  where amount > 1 
  group by name, category
) as s on s.name = t.name and s.category = t.category
order by s.total desc;
```

if you want only 10 products add `limit 10` to the subquery